# app server(EC2) security group inbound rules for RDS traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I have a web server , app server and RDS postgresql instance in my custom VPC.

I have this security group set up for to RDS
[image]

have postgresql for 0.0.0.0/0 just to connect from PG admin.

I have this security group set up for App server.

[image]

both the security group in source are my web server sg and also add sg of RDS as a experimental thing

Issue here is when i remove "all traffic" rule from my appserver's sg, it can't connect with RDS instance.
I am trying to figure out what traffic is it looking for? as obviously keeping all traffic as a rule is not a good practice.

Could any one let me know

Comment: This shouldn't happen, as this is an inbound rule for the app server only. Can you confirm how you're identifying the connection issue? :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams will drop you a mail

Comment: The design is: ELB with  listeners on http:80 and 8080 which points to my web server which intern points to my app server and RDS. 
All the machines are inside a custom VPC.